# Laravel - Send email when new entry is inserted in db?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a case where users can save their searches (it is saved in a table with user id and id of the searched item). What I really want is to send an email to that user every time when new item is inserted in the database. For example, if user saved search for PlayStation 4, I want to alert the user (via email) that new article about PS4 is released. Articles are stored in another table.

At the moment I'm not sure how to start. I've been reading official docs about Events and Handlers, but it's not still clear to me...
Btw. I'm using Laravel 5.3 and Mailgun for emails.

Comment: It's like use subscribe to a certain "items" in your database right? Can you do a select query to find out users by the category they subscribe? If that's the case you can email the set of users. You will have to set up the email function first, (web services, security, access rights etc), This is just from basic SQL point of view.

Comment: I could, but I need email alert for only specific item subscription (saved search). For example PS4 is in Electronics category, but I don't need all articles related to Electornics, just PS4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for laravel notifications

```
// create new notification class
php artisan make:notification ArticlePublished

// to edit the view run this
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

and then when a new article is stored just add this line of code in your controller store method:

```
$user->notify(new ArticlePublished);
```

Here is a great video about that:
https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/9

Comment: This is quite helpful. Thx! I need also to send emails daily or weekly (based on user's choice). But probably there are built in functions for this, I think I saw them somewhere...